# proving a property of transfer function in the s-plane and the complex domain

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, laplace-transform, control-theory, transfer-theory

For a given transfer function (in the s-plane) we've a general form that looks like:

$$\text{H}\left(\text{s}\right)=\frac{\text{X}\left(\text{s}\right)}{\text{Y}\left(\text{s}\right)}\tag1$$

This kind of transfer function that I studying right now, is in the context of electrical engineering. Now, in the study I focus on passive components, like capacitors, inductors and resistors. Using the complex impedance of those components, that gives me:

1. Resistor:
   $$\underline{\text{Z}}_\text{R}=\text{R}\space\left[\Omega\right]\tag2$$
2. Capacitor:
   $$\underline{\text{Z}}_\text{C}=\frac{1}{\text{j}\omega\text{C}}\space\left[\Omega\right]\tag3$$
   Where $\text{j}^2=-1$
3. Inductor:
   $$\underline{\text{Z}}_\text{L}=\text{j}\omega\text{L}\space\left[\Omega\right]\tag4$$
   Where $\text{j}^2=-1$

For studying them in the s-plane I can just substitute:

$$\text{s}=\text{j}\omega\space\space\space\to\space\space\space\underline{\text{H}}\left(\text{j}\omega\right)=\frac{\underline{\text{X}}\left(\text{j}\omega\right)}{\underline{\text{Y}}\left(\text{j}\omega\right)}\tag5$$

Because the inductor and capacitor don't involve any real part.

Now, to find an interesting point I want to solve:

$$\Re\left\{\underline{\text{H}}\left(\text{j}\omega\right)\right\}=\Im\left\{\underline{\text{H}}\left(\text{j}\omega\right)\right\}\tag6$$

And I want the solution to $(6)$ to be the same as the solution to the poles and zeros of the s-plane transfer function.

> Question: How can I prove for which transfer functions this hold?! That setting the real and imaginary part of the complex transfer function equal give me the same result for $\omega$ as when I solve the poles and zeros of the s-plane transfer function (then using $\left|\text{s}\right|=\omega$).

---

**EXAMPLE WHERE IT DOES NOT WORK:**

When we have this transfer function:

$$\underline{\text{H}}\left(\text{j}\omega\right)=\frac{\text{R}_2+\text{j}\omega\text{L}}{\text{R}_1+\text{R}_2+\text{j}\omega\text{L}}\space\space\space\to\space\space\space\text{H}\left(\text{s}\right)=\frac{\text{R}_2+\text{s}\text{L}}{\text{R}_1+\text{R}_2+\text{s}\text{L}}\tag7$$

Now when I solve $\omega$ out of:

$$\Re\left\{\frac{\text{R}_2+\text{j}\omega\text{L}}{\text{R}_1+\text{R}_2+\text{j}\omega\text{L}}\right\}=\Im\left\{\frac{\text{R}_2+\text{j}\omega\text{L}}{\text{R}_1+\text{R}_2+\text{j}\omega\text{L}}\right\}\space\Longleftrightarrow\space\tag8$$
$$\omega=\frac{\text{R}_1\pm\sqrt{\text{R}_1^2-4\cdot\text{R}_2\cdot\left(\text{R}_1-\text{R}_2\right)}}{2\cdot\text{L}}\tag9$$

That gives me different values for $\omega$ when I do it for the poles and zeros in the s-plane:

1. $$\text{R}_2+\text{s}\text{L}=0\space\Longleftrightarrow\space\left|\text{s}\right|=\omega=\left|-\frac{\text{R}_2}{\text{L}}\right|=\frac{\text{R}_2}{\text{L}}\tag{10}$$
2. $$\text{R}_1+\text{R}_2+\text{s}\text{L}=0\space\Longleftrightarrow\space\left|\text{s}\right|=\omega=\left|-\frac{\text{R}_1+\text{R}_2}{\text{L}}\right|=\frac{\text{R}_1+\text{R}_2}{\text{L}}\tag{11}$$

And by, for example:

$$\underline{\text{H}}\left(\text{j}\omega\right)=\frac{\text{j}\omega\text{L}}{\text{R}+\text{j}\omega\text{L}}\tag{12}$$

There it will work.

Comment: Find the frequencies where $\angle H(j\omega)=45^{\circ}$

Comment: What do you mean by "the solution to the poles and zeros of the s-plane"? poles and zeros are just complex values. "solution" does not make much sense. Also, the relation between the question and the explanation about resistor/capacitor/inductor cannot be understood. Off-topic but $\Omega$ is only used for R. Others have different units.

Comment: @polfosol That's not the way because there is another point that gives me  Real=Imaginary at $225^\circ$

Comment: Since j is dimensionless the others do indeed have units of Ohms otherwise the total impedance formula wouldn't work

Comment: @msm English is not my first language (it is Dutch xD). But I mean that the poles and zeros must give the same omega as the solution to real equals imaginary. And officially you're right because I've to use the absolute value of the impedance to use $\Omega$ but I choose it this way to make it clear that $\text{s}=\text{j}\omega$ because it does not contain a real part

Comment: @JanEerland Your English is perfect, but it is still mot clear what you are looking for. You can mention the "interesting point" you are looking for. Also consider assuming a transfer function as an example.

Comment: @msm I've edited my question!

Comment: See my edited answer

Comment: For some unknown reason you put poles and zeros inside $|\cdot|$ which makes them all positive. So for instance in your example $\omega=\frac{R_2}{L}$ is not an actual zero, but rather makes the real and imaginary parts of the numerator equal.

Comment: @msm that is true, but when I dont use the absolute value, I get a complex number for s and in practical use we want to know.omega to set a particular frequency because $\omgea=2\pi f$

Comment: Dude, you have waited this long. What's the rush now?! $$\;$$ _Give me back my precious checkmark_ `;)`

Comment: There is no problem, but I want to continue with my research and you told me that you will edit it in a few hours so I waiting for it

Comment: @polfosol I want to give you the checkmark back, but then the answer has to be something I can use and what your answer contains now is a vote up and if you want that I accept the answer then it has to be edited as you promist.

Comment: @JanEerland Haven't you seen my edit? It's waiting for your confirmation since last night

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that every transfer function can be written in the form of:
$$H(j\omega)=\frac{X(j\omega)}{Y(j\omega)}=\frac{A+j\omega B}{C+j\omega D}$$
where $A,B,C,D$ are **real** functions of $\omega$. If the system has a zero at $\omega_0$ then:
$$X(j\omega_0)=0\implies H(j\omega_0)=0\implies\Re\{H\}|_{\omega_0}=\Im\{H\}|_{\omega_0}=0$$
So the desired property always holds for the system's zeros.

By multiplying both numerator and denominator of $H$ into $C-j\omega D$, we can safely say that if $\Re\{H\}=\Im\{H\}$ then:
$$AC+\omega^2 BD=\omega(BC-AD)$$
The system's poles are the solution of $C+j\omega D=0$. So we have to investigate these two equations simultaneously:
$$\begin{cases}
C(\omega)+j\omega D(\omega)=0\\
AC+\omega^2 BD=\omega(BC-AD)
\end{cases} \label{*}\tag{*}$$
From the first equation, it is evident that either $C(0)=0$ or $|\omega|=\left|\frac CD\right|$ which implies $\omega^2=\frac{C^2}{D^2}$. Putting this into the second equation results in:
$$AC+\frac{BC^2}{D}=\pm\left(AC-\frac{BC^2}{D}\right)$$
and note that only one of $+$ or $−$ can be the correct sign based on the location of the pole.

In conclusion, if the system has a pole in $\omega=0$ then $C(0)=0$ implies $A(0)C(0)=0$ and the $\eqref{*}$ conditions hold.

If the system has a pole at $\omega_1\ne 0$ and $C(\omega_1)\ne 0$ then only **one** of these two equations must hold (based on the location of $\omega_1$):
$$\begin{align}
A(\omega_1)C(\omega_1)&=0\\
B(\omega_1)C(\omega_1)&=0
\end{align}$$
which means either $A(\omega_1)=0$ or $B(\omega_1)=0$. In your second example, we have $A\equiv 0$.

Also note that since $\omega_1$ is a pole, if $C(\omega_1)=0$ then we must have $D(\omega_1)=0$ and the conditions of $\eqref{*}$ are satisfied.

Comment: First of all thanks for your answer. But this is not what I mean in my question. Can you look in my edited question, I've edit a counterexample in it, where it does not work.

Comment: So, $\text{A}$ is a function of $\omega$ so we can write $\text{A}\left(\omega\right)$ the same for $\text{B}$,$\text{C}$ and $\text{D}$. Then why does it not hold for my first example?

Comment: @JanEerland Because in your first example, $A(\omega)=R_2$ and $C(\omega)=R_1+R_2$

Comment: Maybe I'm blind, but I don't see how this answers my question. Because when can I say, you can use both ways and when can I say you can't use one of those two? If I understand it correct then one of these equations has to hold, namely: $\text{A}\left(\omega\right)\cdot\text{C}\left(\omega\right)=0$ or $\text{B}\left(\omega\right)\cdot\text{C}\left(\omega\right)=0$?

Comment: @Downvoter please complete your feedback by stating what's wrong

Comment: I've another question: When $A$, $B$, $C$ and $D$ are real functions of $\omega$, then when you do: $$C+j\omega D=0\implies|\omega|=\left|\frac CD\right|\implies\omega^2=\frac{C^2}{D^2}$$ then you do not solve for $\omega$, because there can be an $\omega$ in the real functions of $C$ or $D$??!

Comment: What happends when $C(\omega)+j\omega D(\omega)=0$?

Comment: @JanEerland I didn't get what you mean. I said that for a transfer function, your desired property holds when $(*)$ is satisfied for a specific $\omega$. If the system has a pole at some $\omega$, then $C(\omega)+j\omega D(\omega)=0$. By the way, it seems that we need to chat a little bit. Just drop me your email or whatsapp number or whatever you are comfortable with, and I will contact you