# Multiplying an imaginary number by a constant in AC circuit, Z impedance

Tags: polar-coordinates

I have a hard time calculating the equation shown in the image attached.
I'm good with the denominator, but I'm confused on how to convert the numerator in polar.

[image: See attached picture].

More precisely, what is $5\times j20$ in polar?

Could someone please explain the steps in obtaining result?

Thank you for your  time.
A person preparing for a test tomorrow

Comment: I am more used to seeing things written in the form $a+bi$ rather than $a+jb$ but assuming these mean the same thing, we would have $5\times j20=5\times j\times 20=j\times 100 = 0+j100$

Comment: Yesss!!! Thank you. That was the answer I was looking, and got the same. From this, I replaced this with the numerator, converted the fraction to polar, proceed the calculation and got the same answer as in the picture!
Thank you so much

Comment: The topic of complex-values of impedance for [RLC circuits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RLC_circuit) has come up in a few previous Questions, such as [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2074631/proving-a-property-of-transfer-function-in-the-s-plane-and-the-complex-domain).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In polar coordinates you have that
 - the numerator is $5 \cdot j20=j100=100 \, e^{j \pi /2}$.
 - the denominator is $5 + j20=\sqrt{5^2+20^2}\, e^{j \arctan{(20/4)}}$.

But to rationalize the formula you cite, you do not need to go through polar. Just multiply over and below the fraction for $5-j20$
$$
\eqalign{
  & {{5 \cdot j20} \over {5 + j20}} = {{\left( {5 - j20} \right)j100} \over {\left( {5 - j20} \right)\left( {5 + j20} \right)}} =   \cr 
  &  = {{\left( {5 - j20} \right)j100} \over {\left( {25 + 400} \right)}} = {{2000 + j500} \over {425}} =   \cr 
  &  = {{80} \over {17}} + j{{20} \over {17}} \cr} 
$$

Comment: Indeed no polar conversion is needed by looking at your solution. Gracias, Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac {5\times 20j}{5+20j}=\frac {20j}{1+4j}=$$
$$\frac {20j}{1+4j}\frac {1-4j}{1-4j}=$$
$$\frac {20 (j+4)}{1^2+4^2}=\frac {80}{17}+j\frac {20}{17} $$

you can finish.

Comment: That is a much simpler way of solving without using the polar! Thank you!

Comment: @Emergeon no problem .